# How do I return JSON data?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to return JSON data but I have no clue on how to do it. I get this error message "Cannot convert return expression of type '[Plant]' to return type 'Plant'". I sort of understand this error message, it means I can't convert one type to another type. But not sure how to solve this issue. Please see my code below:

```swift
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct PlantResponse: Codable {
    let data : [Plant]
}

struct Plant: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let commonName: String         // camelCase
    let slug: String
    let scientificName: String     // camelCase
    let year: Int
    let bibliography: String
    let author: String
    let status: String
    let rank: String
    let familyCommonName: String   // camelCase
    let family: String
    let genusId: Int               // camelCase
    let genus: String
    let imageUrl: String           // camelCase
    let synonyms: [String]         // an array of strings
    let links: Links               // a custom type, defined below
    let Plant: [Plant]
}

extension Plant {
    struct Links: Codable {
        let `self`: String
        let plant: String
        let genus: String
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var plant: Plant?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if let plant {
                Text("There is data")
                    .font(.title)
            } else {
                Text("No data available")
            }
        }
        .padding(20.0)
        .task {
            do {
                plant = try await fetchPlantsFromAPI()
            } catch {
                plant = nil
            }
        }
    }
}

func fetchPlantsFromAPI() async throws -> Plant {
    let url = URL(string: "https://trefle.io/api/v1/plants? token=d321f518jTdU1t-doZQif3jpzzW9V0mk3nLnDssF1vY&filter[common_name]=beach%20strawberry")!
    do {
   
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        let decoded = try! decoder.decode(PlantResponse.self, from: data)
        print(decoded.data)
        return decoded.data //Cannot convert return expression of type '[Plant]' to return type 'Plant'
    } catch {
        throw error
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change `func fetchPlantsFromAPI() async throws -> Plant {` to `func fetchPlantsFromAPI() async throws -> [Plant] {`. Then you need to update your `View` to deal with the array of `Plant`.

Comment: Hello - I think I tried that. But please have a look. This line has now been changed "@State var plant: Plant?" to this "@State var plant: [Plant]?". SO has this line func fetchPlantsFromAPI() async throws -> [Plant]. Is that right? If so, I can't access any of the members of Plant. Unless I have misunderstood the array part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is pointing out that the API returns an array of `Plant`, i.e. `[Plant]`, so change the method signature accordingly:

```swift
func fetchPlantsFromAPI() async throws -> [Plant] {…}
```

Then change the `@State` variable to be an array:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var plants: [Plant] = []

    var body: some View {
        List(plants) { plant in
            Text(plant.commonName)
        }
        .padding(20.0)
        .task {
            do {
                plants = try await fetchPlantsFromAPI()
            } catch {
                print(error)
                plants = []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And, I would declare `Plant` to be `Identifiable` and `Sendable`:

```swift
struct Plant: Codable, Identifiable, Sendable {…}
```

---

Testing this, I see a few additional issues:

1. I would use `URLComponents` to make sure the query is properly escaped:

   ```swift
   func fetchPlantsFromAPI() async throws -> [Plant] {
       guard var components = URLComponents(string: "https://trefle.io/api/v1/plants") else {
           throw URLError(.badURL)
       }

       components.queryItems = [
           URLQueryItem(name: "token", value: "…"),
           URLQueryItem(name: "filter[common_name]", value: "beach strawberry")
       ]

       guard let url = components.url else {
           throw URLError(.badURL)
       }

       let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)

       let decoder = JSONDecoder()
       decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
       let decoded = try decoder.decode(PlantResponse.self, from: data)
       return decoded.data
   }
   ```
2. I would avoid `try!`. As you see in my revised example above, `try` is sufficient. You do not want your app crashing if there is a coding error.
3. There is no point in a `do`-`try`-`catch` if all you are doing in the `catch` is rethrowing the error. Again, I have removed that from point 1, above.
4. You have added a `Plant` property to `Plant` type. You should remove that:

   ```swift
   struct Plant: Codable, Identifiable, Sendable {
       let id: Int
       let commonName: String         // camelCase
       let slug: String
       let scientificName: String     // camelCase
       let year: Int
       let bibliography: String
       let author: String
       let status: String
       let rank: String
       let familyCommonName: String   // camelCase
       let family: String
       let genusId: Int               // camelCase
       let genus: String
       let imageUrl: String           // camelCase
       let synonyms: [String]         // an array of strings
       let links: Links               // a custom type, defined below
   //    let Plant: [Plant]
   }
   ```

   If we look at the JSON, there is no `Plant` key within the array of plants:

   ```json
   {
       "data": [
           {
               "id": 263319,
               "common_name": "Beach strawberry",
               "slug": "fragaria-chiloensis",
               "scientific_name": "Fragaria chiloensis",
               "year": 1768,
               "bibliography": "Gard. Dict. ed. 8 : n.° 4 (1768)",
               "author": "(L.) Mill.",
               "status": "accepted",
               "rank": "species",
               "family_common_name": "Rose family",
               "genus_id": 12147,
               "image_url": "https://bs.plantnet.org/image/o/8ee87e6f94833055db1c7df5fc07761852b7b1eb",
               "synonyms": [
                   "Fragaria vesca var. chiloensis",
                   "Potentilla chiloensis"
               ],
               "genus": "Fragaria",
               "family": "Rosaceae",
               "links": {
                   "self": "/api/v1/species/fragaria-chiloensis",
                   "plant": "/api/v1/plants/fragaria-chiloensis",
                   "genus": "/api/v1/genus/fragaria"
               }
           }
       ],
       "links": {
           "self": "/api/v1/plants?filter%5Bcommon_name%5D=beach+strawberry",
           "first": "/api/v1/plants?filter%5Bcommon_name%5D=beach+strawberry\u0026page=1",
           "last": "/api/v1/plants?filter%5Bcommon_name%5D=beach+strawberry\u0026page=1"
       },
       "meta": {
           "total": 1
       }
   }
   ```
5. I would decode API errors, so we can handle them gracefully. E.g.,

   ```swift
   struct FailureResponse: Codable {
       let error: Bool
       let messages: String
   }

   enum PlantError: Error {
       case apiError(Int, String)
       case invalidResponse(URLResponse)
   }

   func fetchPlantsFromAPI() async throws -> [Plant] {
       guard var components = URLComponents(string: "https://trefle.io/api/v1/plants") else {
           throw URLError(.badURL)
       }

       components.queryItems = [
           URLQueryItem(name: "token", value: "…"),
           URLQueryItem(name: "filter[common_name]", value: "beach strawberry")
       ]

       guard let url = components.url else {
           throw URLError(.badURL)
       }

       let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)

       let decoder = JSONDecoder()
       decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

       guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
           throw PlantError.invalidResponse(response)
       }

       guard 200...299 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
           let errorObject = try decoder.decode(FailureResponse.self, from: data)
           throw PlantError.apiError(httpResponse.statusCode, errorObject.messages)
       }

       return try decoder
           .decode(PlantResponse.self, from: data)
           .data
   }
   ```
6. FWIW, I would be inclined to make the API code generic, so it can work with any of the endpoints (so we do not have to repeat this code all over the place). Perhaps:

   ```swift
   struct SuccessResponse<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
       let data: T
   }

   struct FailureResponse: Decodable {
       let error: Bool
       let messages: String
   }

   struct Plant: Codable, Identifiable, Sendable {
       let id: Int
       let commonName: String         // camelCase
       let slug: String
       let scientificName: String     // camelCase
       let year: Int
       let bibliography: String
       let author: String
       let status: String
       let rank: String
       let familyCommonName: String   // camelCase
       let family: String
       let genusId: Int               // camelCase
       let genus: String
       let imageUrl: String           // camelCase
       let synonyms: [String]         // an array of strings
       let links: Plant.Links         // a custom type, defined below
   }

   extension Plant {
       struct Links: Codable {
           let `self`: String
           let plant: String
           let genus: String
       }
   }

   enum ApiError: Error {
       case apiError(Int, String)
       case invalidResponse(URLResponse)
   }

   func urlForPlantSearch(_ string: String) throws -> URL {
       guard var components = URLComponents(string: "https://trefle.io/api/v1/plants") else {
           throw URLError(.badURL)
       }

       components.queryItems = [
           URLQueryItem(name: "token", value: apiToken),
           URLQueryItem(name: "filter[common_name]", value: string)
       ]

       guard let url = components.url else {
           throw URLError(.badURL)
       }

       return url
   }

   func fetchPlantsFromAPI() async throws -> [Plant] {
       let url = try urlForPlantSearch("beach strawberry")

       return try await fetchFromAPI(url: url)
   }

   // Make this generic so we can reuse this code with any query

   private func fetchFromAPI<T: Decodable>(url: URL) async throws -> T {
       let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)

       let decoder = JSONDecoder()
       decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

       guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
           throw ApiError.invalidResponse(response)
       }

       guard 200...299 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
           let errorObject = try decoder.decode(FailureResponse.self, from: data)
           throw ApiError.apiError(httpResponse.statusCode, errorObject.messages)
       }

       return try decoder
           .decode(SuccessResponse<T>.self, from: data)
           .data
   }
   ```

Comment: Hey @Rob - Thanks for your reply. No errors now, but when I run it, I just get [] in the executable section. Does that mean the array is basically empty?

Comment: OH MY GOD!!! THIS WORKED!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH ROB. I have been stuck on this a week. It actually displays "Beech strawberry". I think I just wasn't passing the URL properly and did't declare the array properly in the View section. Legend, Thank you so much! DO you have any tips for somenone new to swift? Its been a while since I programmed too.

Comment: Another tip is to gracefully handle API errors. Added point 5, above. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks Rob. I will integrate these too. You are a star!

Comment: If you start calling multiple endpoints, best practice would be to make the API code [generic](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/generics) and abstract the API URL building and API fetch query out of `fetchPlantsFromAPI`. This might feel a little too complicated, but it would be best practice, to avoid code duplication as you start adding more and more endpoints to your app.

Comment: Cheers Rob. I will keep in mind. For now, it’s just developing the app